# How to use select for update properly?

Tags: mysql, locking

I would like to lock rows before updating, I have the following codes:

```
select * from package where package.id = ? for update;
update
        package
set
        package.txt = ?,
        
where
        package.id = ?
```

I receive an error message by doing it. and not able to find the correct way.
If my SQL does not have `select * from package where package.id = ? for update;`, it works perfectly.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are locking the same table that you are updating, you do not need to lock the row as the update query would automatically lock it:

MyISAM: locks the table

InnoDB: lock the row